# How to remove the kill prompt of a python script?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script that uses Tkinter, the quit button I have implemented pops up a prompt on the python shell after pressing it, which it didn't do on Windows when I wrote the code and tested it. Is there a way to remove this prompt?

The options menu on the python shell only has a checkbox for a save-before-run-prompt, but nothing to remove the kill prompt.

Here's the relevant code:

```
quit_button = tk.Button(button_frame, 
                     text="QUIT", 
                     fg="red",
                     command=quit)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `quit()` and `exit()` functions are built into IDLE rather than special to the Pi. Looks like there's already an answer to your question at: [How to remove exit(0) pop-up in Python IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988425/how-to-remove-exit0-pop-up-in-python-idle) on Stack Overflow, though.

Comment: It's not `quit()` it's `quit` as a parameter of `tk.button()` regardless I imported sys and tried `command= sys.exit()` , `command= sys.exit(0)` , `command= lamdba: sys.exit()` , `command= lamdba: sys.exit(0)` and defining it as a separate function with sys.exit(0). None of these worked, the errors ranged from not running at all to leaving the program hanging after pressing the button.

Comment: Ideally you should use `master.destroy` as your callback in this case then, to tell Tkinter to quit properly, with `master` being your root element. It seems that sys.exit doesn't mesh well with Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to make a function and call it.

```
quit_button = tk.Button(button_frame, 
                     text="QUIT", 
                     fg="red",
                     command= lambda: QUIT())
```

The function:

```
def QUIT():
    #additional stuff here
    root.destroy()
```

For example in my case I had to add `camera.stop_preview()` because otherwise it would leave the preview blocking the screen until I closed the python shell.